# How to set max connections in AP configuration of esp8266?

Tags: iot, esp8266, micropython

I want to connect only one client at a time with esp8266. Second client trying to connect should disconnect immediately.But I can't find 'max_connection' like parameter in

`ap.configuration()`

Allowed parameters are essid, password, channel, authmode
Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: keep in mind 4 is the max...

Comment: i know that how to set that in micropython do u know the way

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wifi_softap_set_config()` with `config.max_connections`.

[From reference](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/570)

Comment: I am using python is there a pythonic way of doing that